# Implementing a method onto text in XNA

Tags: c#, text, xna

So I have started to mess around with XNA today and I am still learning C#.  I am trying to produce a main menu for a game.

I have made a sprite font file and am producing the text I want.  The code for this is:

```
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, ">://Start Game [1]", new Vector2(0, 0), Color.LimeGreen);
```

My question is that I have a method to make a typing effect from the "computer" (which I asked a question about a few days ago), but this is in C++.  I have an idea how to convert it into C#, but even if I do convert the code correctly, how do I apply the method onto the text being created?  Is their a more efficient way to print text in XNA?

The code for the typing effect in C++ is:

```
    void typeOutput(string displayString){

        for(int i = 0; i < displayString.length(); i++){

            cout << displayString[i];
            Sleep((rand() + 1)%typeSpeed);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this which is discussed in [this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/34793/200063.aspx). One example from that thread is:

```
// our string will take 3 seconds to appear 
private const float timerLength = 3f; 
private float timer = 0f;
```

Then in your Draw method you add to the timer and use that to determine how much of the string to draw:

```
timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; 

// if the timer is passed timerLength, we just draw the whole string 
if (timer >= timerLength) 
{ 
   spriteBatch.DrawString(myFont, myString, stringPosition, stringColor); 
} 

// otherwise we want to just draw a substring 
else 
{ 
   // figure out how many characters to show based on 
   // the ratio of the timer to the timerLength 
   int numCharsToShow = (int)(myString.Length * (timer / timerLength)); 
   string strToDraw = myString.Substring(0, numCharsToShow);    

   // now just draw the substring instead 
   spriteBatch.DrawString(myFont, strToDraw, stringPosition, stringColor); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't actually use this exact answer, but I found an example on the website you linked that satisfied all my needs: Produce text, make the typing effect, and centers the text. Thank you so much!